# Join Tables and Return data in single row different columns with count of join

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

We have 3 tables in Oracle 11g, need to left join them and return the data in single row different columns with count of the join, Is there any way We can acheive the same.

***Example:***

***Table1: (Employee_Data)***

[image]

***Table2: (Employee_Address)***

[image]

***Table3: (Employee_Role)***

[image]

***Expected Result:***

[image]

Mack has 2 addresses and 2 roles so Emp_Addr_Count is 2, Emp_Role_Count is 2 and the related data is in same row different column.

Kindly note that EMP_ID is unique in Employee_Data table and Employee_Address and Employee_Role could be multiple or zero for a Employee.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: are there any rules for addresses in the expected result? for example is there any maximum number of addresses per user?

Comment: no there are no maximum limit, count will be random.

Comment: If there can be an unknown number of addresses and tasks per user, you have three options: 1) select concatenated strings, e.g. 'Manage task, Ressource Manage'. So you have one addresses column, one tasks column. 2) Use a simple query that selects all rows, then fill the grid in a loop in your app/Webpage yourself. 3) Also in your app/Webpage: write one query to get the maximum number of addresses and tasks, then create another query with all necessary columns based on these numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT E.Emp_Id
    ,E.Emp_Name
    ,E.Emp_Age
    ,NVL(MAX(EA.RN),0)Addr_Count
    ,NVL(MAX(CASE WHEN EA.RN = 1 THEN EA.Emp_Address END),' ')Emp_Address_1
    ,NVL(MAX(CASE WHEN EA.RN = 1 THEN EA.Emp_City END),' ')Emp_City_1
    ,NVL(MAX(CASE WHEN EA.RN = 2 THEN EA.Emp_Address END),' ')Emp_Address_2
    ,NVL(MAX(CASE WHEN EA.RN = 2 THEN EA.Emp_City END),' ')Emp_City_2
    ,NVL(MAX(ER.RN1),0)Role_Count
    ,NVL(MAX(CASE WHEN ER.RN1 = 1 THEN ER.Emp_task END),' ')Emp_task_1
    ,NVL(MAX(CASE WHEN ER.RN1 = 2 THEN ER.Emp_task END),' ')Emp_task_2 FROM Employee_Data E JOIN(
SELECT Emp_Id
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Emp_Id ORDER BY Emp_City desc) RN
    ,Emp_City
    ,Emp_Address
FROM Employee_Address
)EA ON EA.Emp_Id = E.Emp_Id left JOIN(
SELECT Emp_Id
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Emp_Id ORDER BY Emp_Task) RN1
    ,Emp_task
FROM Employee_Role
)ER ON ER.Emp_Id = E.Emp_Id GROUP BY E.Emp_Id,E.Emp_Name,E.Emp_Age
```

**Output:**

```
EMP_ID  EMP_NAME    EMP_AGE ADDR_COUNT  EMP_ADDRESS_1   EMP_CITY_1  EMP_ADDRESS_2   EMP_CITY_2  ROLE_COUNT  EMP_TASK_1  EMP_TASK_2
1       MACK        45      2       HOME PARADISE       MUM         TINDER ONCLAVE  DEL         2           Manage Task Resource Manage
2       JACK        30      1       BLUE PLAZA          MUM                                     1           Code    
3       ANGEL       27      1       HOME PARADISE       MUM                                     0
```

Comment: Hi Dinesh, is there any way we could name the columns dynamically based on number of joins that is Emp_Address_1, Emp_Address_2.

Answer (score 1):

You can join them as in the following statement :

```
WITH t AS
(
 SELECT d.*, a.emp_address, a.emp_city, r.emp_task  
   FROM employee_data d 
   JOIN employee_address a on ( d.emp_id = a.emp_id )
   FULL OUTER JOIN employee_role r on ( d.emp_id = r.emp_id )
)
SELECT emp_id, emp_name, emp_age, count(distinct emp_address) emp_addr_count, 
       min(emp_address) emp_address_1, max(emp_city) emp_city_1, 
       decode(min(emp_address),max(emp_address),null,max(emp_address)) emp_address_2, 
       decode(min(emp_city),max(emp_city),null,min(emp_city)) emp_city_2,
       count(distinct emp_task) emp_role_count, min(emp_task) emp_task_1, 
       decode(min(emp_task),max(emp_task),null,max(emp_task)) emp_task_2        
  FROM t
 GROUP BY emp_id, emp_name, emp_age     
 ORDER BY emp_id;
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/951289/1)